# phpexcel version 1.8 does not allow loading .xlsm files and save

Tags: php, phpexcel

When I load .xlsx or .xls files then it work properly. See the following code 
//load our new PHPExcel library
        $this->load->library('excel');

```
    $file = "files/test.xlsx";

    $excel2 = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createReader('Excel2007');
    $excel2 = $excel2->load($file); // Empty Sheet
    //print_r($excel2); 

    $excel2->setActiveSheetIndex(1);
    $excel2->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('C6', '4');
    $excel2->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('A1', '5');
    $excel2->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('A2', '3');

    $excel2->setActiveSheetIndex(2);
    $excel2->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('A7', '4');

    $filename='Registration_Report.xlsx';
    header('Content-Type: application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet'); //mime type
    header('Content-Disposition: attachment;filename="'.$filename.'"');  //tell browser what's the file name
    header('Cache-Control: max-age=0'); //no cache

    $objWriter = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createWriter($excel2, 'Excel2007');
    $objWriter->save('php://output');
```

But when i am loading macro file i.e. .xlsm then nothing happens. see the following code

//load our new PHPExcel library
        $this->load->library('excel');

```
    $file = "files/test.xlsm";

    $excel2 = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createReader('Excel2007');
    $excel2 = $excel2->load($file); // Empty Sheet
    //print_r($excel2); 

    $excel2->setActiveSheetIndex(1);
    $excel2->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('C6', '4');
    $excel2->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('A1', '5');
    $excel2->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('A2', '3');

    $excel2->setActiveSheetIndex(2);
    $excel2->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('A7', '4');

    $filename='Registration_Report.xlsm';
    header('Content-Type: application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet'); //mime type
    header('Content-Disposition: attachment;filename="'.$filename.'"');  //tell browser what's the file name
    header('Cache-Control: max-age=0'); //no cache

    $objWriter = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createWriter($excel2, 'Excel2007');
    $objWriter->save('php://output');
```

I am using latest version of phpExcel i.e. 1.8 and the class does contain the hasMacro function...

Comment: Absolutely nothing happens? Not even a blank screen? No error messages? Nothing written to logs?

Comment: A blank screen appears. No error in php log. I have done lots of R&D and I found that phpexcel does not support macro files but that was for the old version. I am using latest version.

Comment: were you able to resolve this problem ??